# Layered costmap performance

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, costmap, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After switching to the plugin implementation of costmap_2d in order to be able to work with layers, the layers load extremely slowly and in chunks, it's a bit difficult to explain, so I've included pictures:

Using pre-hydro configuration:

[image: image description]

Using plugins:

[image: image description]

It's a problem since it also affects the planners.

Here are my config files:

costmap_common_params.yaml:

```
  obstacle_range: 3.5
  raytrace_range: 4.0
  robot_radius: 0.4
  inflation_radius: 0.7

  obstacle_layer:
    observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
    laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: /sensor_link, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /navbot/scan_data, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

global_costmap_params:

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: /platform
  update_frequency: 5.0
  static_map: true
  plugins:
    - {name: inflation_layer,   type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer", output: "screen"}
    - {name: static_map,        type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
    - {name: obstacle_layer,    type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer", output: "screen"}
```

local_costmap_params.yaml:

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: /platform
  update_frequency: 8.0
  publish_frequency: 4.0
  rolling_window: true
  static_map: false
  width: 6.0
  height: 6.0
  resolution: 0.05
  plugins:
    - {name: inflation_layer,        type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer", output: "screen"}
    - {name: obstacle_layer,         type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer", output: "screen"}
```

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315100/layered-costmap-performance/) by [SleepyTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39792/sleepyturtle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2019-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The order of your layers is probably not what you intended. Move the inflation layer from the first position to the last position in each configuration.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2019-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SleepyTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39792/sleepyturtle/) on 2019-02-09**:
Thank you, I'll try it out on Monday and update the question.

EDIT: That solved the problem, thank you again.

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2020-07-04**:
@david-lu so the order in which you add the layers makes a difference? Could you please provide a reference link where I can read more about it?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2020-07-10**:
http://wustl.probablydavid.com/entry200.html

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2020-07-14**:
Thanks a lot for sharing the paper, helped me a lot to understand. So if I have laser scanner+sonar, what should be the order of my layers?
Please tell me if this is correct:

1. Static
2. Obstacle
3. Sonar
4. Inflation
   Should inflation always be the last item?
   Thanks again

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2020-07-16**:
That looks fine. Whether you switch Obstacle and Sonar depends on what kind of obstacles you'll see. Inflation is very often the last item, but I won't say always.